# Is it bad style or incorrect to access va_arg macro by reference?

Tags: c, reference, variadic-functions

I got a line of code where this is pretty useful:

```
void *test;
/*...*/
test = &va_arg(arg_list, int);
```

I was just trying this, as i thought, this is a macro and not a function, so it might work.
I didn't really was expecting it to work, but it does exactly what I want.

But now I'm not sure about the lifetime of the address and other risks which may occur of this style.

Could anyone tell me why using the reference of the `va_arg` 's value this way is safe / unsafe?

Comment: I don't see anything in the specification that requires `va_arg(ap, type)` to be an lvalue.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis So this might be invalid on some enviroments?

Comment: @meaning-matters I think he is saying the opposite. Since standard says `va_arg` only returns value, it doesn't make a promise that you could take the address of it. So it would be unsafe to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C99 standard, section 7.15.1.1 (emphasis mine):

> The va_arg macro **expands to an expression** that has the specified
>   type and the value of the next argument in the call.

This implies that `va_arg` does not necessarily evaluate to an lvalue; taking the address of whatever it expands to is unsafe: an lvalue can be used as an expression, but not every expression is an lvalue. Consider the expression `3+4`. It doesn't make sense to take the address of that.

So, no, you shouldn't do it.

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments, taking the address of an expression that is not an lvalue will cause a compilation error. So, if the code compiles, then it should be safe. The unportability issues arise from the fact that it may not compile in other platforms where `va_arg()` expands to something that is not an lvalue.

Comment: If it's not an lvalue then wouldn't it be a compile error? Not sure why it would be unsafe, either it compiles or it doesn't...

Comment: @Mehrdad Expanding to an expression doesn't mean that the expression, in this specific case, isn't an lvalue. It may be the case that in fact it is, thus compiling successfully. But there is nothing in the standard that guarantees this behavior, so it's not portable.

Comment: So just for me to get it right: the way I'm using the code could result in compile time errors but won't result in runtime errors? right? So keeping the option of looking for alternatives on systems where it won't work that way could result in additional affort, but can't be harmful? Did I get that right?

Comment: I mean if it doesn't compile, then obviously there's nothing unsafe about it. And if it does compile, then I think the behavior is completely well-defined and predictable, so it's completely safe, right?

Comment: @Zaibis and Mehrdad Yep, that is correct. I wasn't very clear about that, let me update my answer.

Comment: Being (or not being) an lvalue is always a property of an *expression* in C. So, the fact that `va_arg` evaluates to an *expression* really says nothing in this context. I'd even say that the more important part of the quote is that it says "has value" instead of "refers to an object". This suggests value context (as opposed to object context), meaning that lvalue-ness of the result is not guaranteed.